# KStream windowed aggregation - partition problems

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a simple cluster setup on AWS with one kafka instance and one zookeeper. Im writing `<String, String>` to this and working to aggregate these values in 10 second windows.

Error message(s) Im getting:

```
DEBUG  o.a.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Sending metadata request {topics=[kafka_test1-write_aggregate-changelog]} to node 100
DEBUG  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Updated cluster metadata version 6 to Cluster(nodes = [12.34.56.78:9092 (id: 100 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = kafka_test1-write_aggregate-changelog, partition = 1, leader = 100, replicas = [100,], isr = [100,], Partition(topic = kafka_test1-write_aggregate-changelog, partition = 0, leader = 100, replicas = [100,], isr = [100,]])
DEBUG  o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - Attempt to fetch offsets for partition kafka_test1-write_aggregate-changelog-0 failed due to obsolete leadership information, retrying.
```

The `cluster metadata` # keeps advancing indefinitely.

Code:

```
KStreamBuilder kStreamBuilder = new KStreamBuilder();
KStream<String, String> lines = kStreamBuilder.stream(TOPIC);

KTable<Windowed<String>, String>  dbwriteTable = lines.aggregateByKey(
            new DBAggregateInit(),
            new DBAggregate(),
            TimeWindows.of("write_aggregate", 10000));

dbwriteTable.toStream().print();

KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(kStreamBuilder, streamsConfig);

kafkaStreams.start();
```

Where `DBAggregateInit` and `DBAggregate` are stubbed out to log to DEBUG when anything hits them. No other function.

None of these stubbed functions ever gets hit.

Not sure what step(s) I've missed here. If I `.foreach()` or do a simple read on this topic it seems to work ok.

#### FWIW:

Ive had similar issues with partitions when I let kafka create my topic instead of using `kafka-topic --create --topic ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this sort of error is due to the fact that I was running zookeeper and kafka as different users and there were likely permissions issues in the various data folders.

Once both services were run as root and all relevant data files were erased / recreated these errors went away.